# How can I search for all translate attributes on page and replace their values?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, dom, translate

How can I query the entire HTML page for a specific attribute and either remove it or replace the value?

I was thinking something like this (translate being the attribute name):

```
$('[translate]').remove();

$('[translate]').value('replace the value of the attribute');
```

Comment: This question is unclear: what elements have the attribute `translate` (node type)? What establish if the element should be removed or changed? **Edit:** on re-reading, do you want to change or remove the attribute from the node?

Comment: translate is an attribute you can use with angular.

Comment: The elements could be anything: div, p, a, span, etc

Comment: I would like to either put a value of = "" (meaning empty) or just remove the attribute all together.

Comment: `$('[translate]').removeAttr( 'translate' );` to remove, `$('[translate]').attr( 'translate', 'value' );` to change.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('a').click(function(v){
      var changeVal = "other_val"
      $("[translate]").attr("translate",changeVal)
       $("[translate]").html(changeVal)
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div translate="some_val">some_val
</div>
<div translate="some_val">some_val
</div>
<a href="javascript:void(0)">Change attr</a>
```

Hi! This snippet may be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

### Here is an Example:-  You can use nativeElement & querySelector` for DOM Manipulation.

### app.component.html

```
<div class="tabs tabsMenu" #tabs>
abc
</div>
   <div id="tab-1" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">abc</div>
 <div id="tab-2" class="tab-content rmpm" role="tabpanel">abc</div>
```

### app.component.ts

```
 @ViewChild('tabs') public tabs;
  constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    this.el = el;
}

 let tabsEl = this.tabs.nativeElement;
    this.removeActive(tabsEl.querySelectorAll('.active'));
this.setActive([
      tabsEl.querySelector(`#${id}`)
]);

 setActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className += ' active';
    });
  }

  removeActive(elems) {
    elems.forEach((el) => {
      el.className = el.className.replace(' active', '');
    });
```